# Xcode Issue Adding Action

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working on a UI.  When I want to add an action, I drag from the control to the code in the assistant editor.  When the action is created, the code is inserted in to the middle of other functions, causing errors.  This has been happening more and ore frequently.  I even updated Xcode to the latest (7.3.1), to try and fix it.  Here's an example of what happens:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    @IBAction func doneClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    //self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
}
```

You can see that the doneClicked Action is inserted in to the middle of `viewDidLoad`.  The only way to fix it is to cut the code out of the middle of `viewDidLoad`, paste it lower, and then reconnect the action to the control.

It's getting really annoying.  Is there any way to fix it or is there a better way to create the actions without doing it this way?

Comment: Try to ceate action manually and then connect them to buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an Xcode bug because I have had similar problem too. After selecting Assistant Editor, you can fix this by selecting your file from automatic menu. This is what fixed it for me. You can refer the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Going from manual to automatic did the trick.  It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

The `viewDidLoad` method is initially load the `ViewController`,if your `doneClicked` is method, you will set the method in out of the `viewDidLoad`, for example see below code,

if you want call the doneClicked method, just call this way,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.doneClicked("")        
}

@IBAction func doneClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
     // put your code
}
```

hope its helpful

Comment: Thanks.  I understand this.  My problem is that when I drag from the control to the code in the assistant editor to create the action, Xcode is putting the new action in the middle of existing functions.